# How do you accept the right answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I just asked a question and three people gave 3 really good answers. Each of them is very useful and both the comments and answers help clear up a lot of things. How do I then go about choosing which answer I accept?

Comment: See [What factors should be considered to accept an answer: Time, completeness or what?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3656/what-factors-should-be-considered-to-accept-an-answer-time-completeness-or-wha) and
[Are there codified or at least customary acceptance criteria?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3772/are-there-codified-or-at-least-customary-acceptance-criteria)

Comment: Close as duplicate, no?

Answer (score 9):

There are no *rules* stipulating how you make a decision: choosing an answer to accept is a very subjective issue.

Now, if you really cannot choose, one option (which I use myself in other Stackexchange sites) is to flip a coin (roll a die etc.) and randomly choose one. Then leave a comment on the other answers saying that you appreciated the help, but software limitations allows you to accept one answer, and so on and so forth.

For a lot of the users here, the primary functions of the check-mark is

1. To indicate the question is solved
2. To thank the answerer.

For those users whether they actually get the 15 rep point isn't that important: they would be perfectly happy knowing that their efforts are not misspent and you found their help to be useful.

Comment: Note that at least from personal experience, 'flip a coin, cringe when it comes up one way and realize that you preferred the other choice all along' is also an excellent method for deciding which of two choices you prefer...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I like this comment more than the answer :).(I like the answer also)